# What does "It is as good as any" mean?

Tags: meaning

While I was watching an episode of The Walking Dead (which is a zombie show), a father watching a house tells his son, "it is as good as any"; what does it mean? First I thought, he wants to say, "it is like other houses" that is full of zombies. But I saw, they entered the house. So did he try to mean the opposite?

Answer (score 6):

No, you're actually right.

Saying that something is **as good as any** means that this one (in your case, a house) is neither better nor worse than the others - it's as good (or, as bad, depending on how you look at it).

Comment: I actually think that in some usage, this can be used to add emphasis to a statement. See M-W's definition of the similar phrase "[as anything](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20anything)". In the context provided by OP, I think you're correct, but it's worth noting the phrase itself is somewhat context dependent.

Answer (score 3):

(I wouldn't say OP is "right" since there were two opposite meanings suggested.)

**"As good as any" means choosing this house is "exactly just as good" or **equivalent** to choosing any other house.**  In this case, the word "good" has no connotation that "this is a good choice".

**There's also a sense of requirement-to-make-a-choice without-any-knowledge.**  Suppose you have to disable a device by cutting one of three wires within 15 seconds.  If you don't cut a wire, then of course disaster ensues.  You have to cut one of them.  You have to choose one.  Whichever you choose is as good as any.